# Does Pandas release the GIL for string comparison?

Tags: python, pandas, large-files

I'm thinking of using Pandas to compare the values in certain columns between two large CSV's. The comparison is just a simple Pandas compare. Something like below:

```
flagged_cars = cars.loc[cars.name_L != cars.name_R].copy()
```

Does Pandas string comparison require the GIL? Will Pandas use the additional cores in my laptop's CPU?

I'm aware that I could write this without using pandas but it would be very convenient if Pandas worked like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm 8 months late to your question, but no, pandas does not release the GIL for string comparison.

Comment: how did u find out?

Comment: Hello @yellowsir pandas release the GIL on Cython operations, but string comparison is implemented in Python